# Looping not Working java

Tags: java, loops

I'm Creating a LogIn Program in Java. I'm almost done after working so hard but i have one last problem.  I wanted my program to have only 3 login attempts before it closes, the thing is after you input wrong pass and user it keeps on looping without the user entering the username and password again and  then it closes after 3 loops. Please Help me.

```
package password;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Password extends JFrame {


public JPasswordField pass;
public JLabel usernameL,passwordL;
public JTextField usernameTF,passwordTF;
private JButton LogInB,CancelB;
private LogInButtonHandler logHandler;
private CancelButtonHandler canHandler;


public Password (){
    usernameL=new JLabel("Username");
    passwordL=new JLabel("Password");
    usernameTF=new JTextField(20);
    passwordTF=new JTextField(20);
   pass=new JPasswordField(10);


  pass.setEchoChar ('•');

    LogInB=new JButton("Log In");
    logHandler=new LogInButtonHandler();
    LogInB.addActionListener(logHandler);

    CancelB=new JButton("Cancel");
    canHandler=new CancelButtonHandler();
    CancelB.addActionListener(canHandler);

    setTitle("Log In");
    Container p=getContentPane();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

    p.add(usernameL);
    p.add(usernameTF);
    p.add(passwordL);
    p.add(pass);
    p.add(LogInB);
    p.add(CancelB);



    setSize(300,200);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

    private class LogInButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        String password=null;
        String user=null;
        boolean isValid;



       Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);




        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {

        try {
            if(i!=0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Username/Password Inccorect Please Try Again: "+i,"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

            if(i==2)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This " +(++i) + "rd login will be your final attempt","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }





            isValid=isValidCred(user,password);
            if(isValid)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome "+user,"Succesful",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
                break;
            }

            if(i==3)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You had "+i+" failed attempts","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
        }

  System.exit(0);











    }



}



public boolean isValidCred(String user, String password) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{

    user = usernameTF.getText();
    password = pass.getText();
     File file=new File("C:\\login\\user.txt");
     File file2=new File("C:\\login\\pass.txt");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line=in.readLine();
        BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));
        String line2=in2.readLine();


    if (user.equals(line) && password.equals(line2))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    }




private class CancelButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
        dispose();
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Password pass=new Password();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a loop inside `actionPerformed` of `LogInButtonHandler`, since that loop wouldn't accept new input after the first failure.

Instead, each time the login button is pressed, you should increment some member variable. `actionPerformed` of `LogInButtonHandler` would test the value of that variable to determine which message to display to the user.

Yuo probably need something like this :

```
private class LogInButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    int i = 0;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String password=null;
    String user=null;
    boolean isValid;

    if (i < 3) {
        isValid=isValidCred(user,password);
        if(isValid) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome "+user,"Succesful",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
            return;
        }
        i++;
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Username/Password Inccorect Please Try Again: "+i,"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    if(i==2) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This " +(++i) + "rd login will be your final attempt","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You had "+i+" failed attempts","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```